# Can't get ng-click working when loaded dynamically from inside a jQuery plugin

Tags: angularjs

Bit of a strange setup, but I'm using a carousel jquery plugin to show some content, and inside that content is a button that I'd like to have an ng-click event on. Everything works beautifully with the widget and angular, except the click.

I'm not sure what I need to do - other answers mention needing to $compile the HTML, but I don't load the HTML the plugin does. Any suggestions welcome. If I can show code that will help let me know, I'm not sure if it would be that helpful.  Here's all I can think of:

```
<div class="items">
  <ul class="bxslider"> <!-- BEGIN SLIDES -->
    <li ng-repeat="item in RecommendedItems" ng-hide="item.show" class="card">
      <span ng-if="item.completeStatus=='completed'"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" /></span>
      <span ng-bind-html="item.content"></span>       
    </li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

In this example, item.content is where the HTML with the ng-click is. The controller has:

```
RecommendedItems.query({}, function(response) {
          if (response && response.length > 0) {
            scope.RecommendedItems = response;

            setTimeout(function(){
              $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                mode: 'horizontal',
                minSlides: 3,
                maxSlides: 3,
                video: true,
                slideWidth: 400,
                slideHeight: 260,
                slideMargin: 20,
                moveSlides: 1,
                pager: false,
                infiniteLoop: false,
                hideControlOnEnd: true
              });
            },1);
          }
        });
```

Comment: Where are you trying to add the ng-click? Could you add a jsfiddle with your solution that isn't working.

Comment: ng-click is inside of item.content - I'll add that to the question, sorry.

Comment: i would say that you load the plugin, after angular evaluates scope. that's probably the reason, why you see everything rendered but not functional. I guess that it will work if you increase timeout (e.g. 5000 instead of 1). But, I think that there should be a better solution to work it out.

Comment: @Ned tried that just now, doesn't work. Think I need a $compile somewhere but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Ok, I now see your updated question. Another ('hacky') solution could be that you compile your item.content in controller, assign it to $scope variable and use it in your template. I'm not sure whether you can do it with setup that you currently have (I can't guess it from pasted code). I see that it is in ng-repeat, so I guess that could be a problem.

Comment: @Ned I gave something like that a try, but wasn't sure how to go about it exactly. When I added $compile(angular.element('.bxslider')(scope), none of the carousel loaded visually but all the elements seemed to be there. Strange. I tried angular.element('.bxslider').html($compile(...)(scope)); as well but that did the same thing.